# How do I copy a formula down a column, whilst ensuring that the reference cell changes as I go

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to pull the information from another sheet as seen below:

=iferror(filter('Form Responses 1'!A:T,'Form Responses 1'!L68="Marketing"),"No results")

The problem is that when the term Marketing is found in "Form Responses 1" source cell it doesn't reflect in the destination sheet.

It works when I use:

=iferror(filter('Form Responses 1'!A:T,'Form Responses 1'!L:L="Marketing"),"No results")

But the problem with this method is that it populates every row in the destination sheet with the information found in the row in the source sheet where marketing is.

I'm stumped; where am I going wrong? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Can you please share a sheet - the way your explaining the question is really confusing to determine which outcome you want. But if you share a sample sheet I can jump in  help configure

Comment: Hey Aurielle, I managed to work it out but I really appreciate the help you were willing to provide. Have a great weekend :)